# input text field inside radio button group

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Is there a way to bind `ngModel` to the `input` text field inside `radio group`? I have a multiple choice radio button group, with the last option as `other` (with input text). Here is what I have so far:

```
 <mat-radio-group fxLayout="column" name="goal_name" [(ngModel)]="goal.name">
          <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let gn of goalNames" name="goal_name" [value]="gn">{{gn}}</mat-radio-button>
          <mat-radio-button value="" name="goal_name">
            <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput placeholder="Other" [(ngModel)]="goal.name" name="something">
            </mat-form-field>
          </mat-radio-button>
        </mat-radio-group>

goalNames = ["buy", "travel", "save",
    "build", "retire"];
```

The problem with this implementation is that the value of `ngmodel` does not binds itself to the value of radio button. Thats why, the radio unchecks everytime the input text changes. Is there someway to implement this requirement?

Comment: Does it bother you if the selected name appears in the input box, even if the "other" option is not selected? For example, if the user selects "travel", you would see "travel" in the input box.

Comment: The whole idea behind have `other` field is to not have any one of the options described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[This stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-fcnkjc)** shows one way to do it. Two properties are used: `goalOption` is bound to the selected radio button value, `customGoalName` is bound to the input text. When any of the two is changed, `goal.name` is updated by calling `updateGoalName` in the property setter.

```
private _goalOption: string = "";
private _customGoalName: string = "";

goal = { name: "" };

goalNames = ["buy", "travel", "save", "build", "retire"];

get goalOption(): string {
  return this._goalOption;
}
set goalOption(value: string) {
  this._goalOption = value;
  this.updateGoalName();
}

get customGoalName(): string {
  return this._customGoalName;
}
set customGoalName(value: string) {
  this._customGoalName = value;
  this.updateGoalName();
}

private updateGoalName(): void {
  this.goal.name = this._goalOption === "other" ? this._customGoalName : this._goalOption;
}
```

The radio button for the custom goal name has the value `other` in the template. The handler of the input event `ngModelChange` makes sure that the `other` radio button is checked when the user types a custom goal name.

```
<mat-radio-group fxLayout="column" name="goal_name" [(ngModel)]="goalOption">
  <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let gn of goalNames" name="goal_name" [value]="gn">{{gn}}</mat-radio-button>
  <mat-radio-button value="other" name="goal_name">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input matInput placeholder="Other" [(ngModel)]="customGoalName" (ngModelChange)="goalOption = 'other'" name="something">
    </mat-form-field>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: is there a way to disable the default selection of the `other` radio option?

Comment: With the current code, only by setting one of the standard options by default.

Comment: There is another annoyance: if you type a text that starts like one of the standard options, that option is automatically selected. That is not very good. I think that the best implementation would be to have a separate variable for the name typed in the input box.

Comment: could there be a solution if we move `other` out of the radio group instead?

Comment: I updated my answer and the stackblitz to show how it works with two variables.

Comment: not working for me: "ERROR Error: mat-form-field must contain a MatFormFieldControl."